# How to segue between ViewControlllers calling ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to transition between two different storyboards, but I don't want to reload the storyboards each time, as they contain UI controls that need to keep their values.

I just want to have two storyboards active and loaded into memory so that I can transition between them without calling the ViewDidLoad function.

Hope that makes sense:)

Comment: I always recommend programming your UI instead of using storyboards. Something like this would be very simple programmed. If you choose to go that route, let me know, and I will write you a snippet.

Comment: If you have some code that holds references to your view controllers after they're loaded, you should be able to present them as needed without going back to their storyboards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.